# What does it mean for a device to be hardwired?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

Recently while reading about security cameras in Shadowrun 5e, I came across a forum post where someone suggested that if you don't want a decker to be able to disable your security cameras, you can hardwire them. From what I understand this means that they are not connected to the matrix, but what is less clear is whether that's all, which leads me to my question: What does it mean for a device to be hardwired in Shadowrun 5e?

Comment: Not sure how this word is used in the SR context, but the usual technical definition of hardwired is basicly "non-programable". The whole software and configuration would be written to some kind of ROM-chip.  In such a case the relevant chip would have to be physically removed and a replacement soldered in.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### It doesn't have wireless capability, meaning that its network must be physically accessed

This was confusing to research, because while I was sure I'd read something in the books on this topic it doesn't use the word *hardwired*! The word *hardwired* appears in the SR5 core rulebook once (excepting the glossary, where it appears twice), and in a narrative section:

> He knew electronics backwards
> and forwards, literally inside and out, and all he had to do, all he
> had to do in the world right now, was beat this maglock and the
> hardwired security system supporting it. (*SR5 Core Rulebook, page 15*).

The term *hardwire* means a specific thing in the supplement *Chrome Flesh*, and refers to something totally different! They grant specific knowledges, similar to skillsofts. Across all of SR5, the only instances of *hardwire* (and variants) that I could find were that single narrative section and discussion of hardwires in (or referring to) *Chrome Flesh*.

The relevant section describing devices that are connected exclusively through wired connections is in the SR5 core rulebook:

> **WIRED SECURITY**
>
> ---
>
> It is possible for a network owner to decide to forgo
> wireless connections
> entirely and
> instead connect
> their system using
> traditional wires.
> This is rare due
> to the inconvenience
> it presents,
> but still an option
> for those mistrusting
> of the security
> wireless offers.
> All Matrix devices
> connect via wireless
> by default,
> with many of the
> less expensive
> ones not having
> a wired connection
> option.
>
> If an organization wants to wire a network,
> the cabling must be purchased and installed throughout
> the location where the network exists. This limits the
> placement of devices and requires maintenance of the
> proper connections. Wired networks are still vulnerable
> in many of the same ways as wireless networks. If a wire
> is breached and tapped anywhere along its length, the
> signals can be intercepted and retransmitted via wireless
> anyway.
>
> It should be noted, though, that between grids,
> hosts, IC, spiders, and GODs, corporations are feeling
> very confident in the security of their wireless networks.
> This means that runners are only likely to encounter
> wired security in the hands of the exceedingly protective
> or paranoid. (*SR5 Core Rulebook, page 356*)

(line breaks mine)

The practical effect of this is that, to do anything (like decking) with a wired-only device you need to physically access that device or a device to which it is physically connected. A wired-only lock can't be disabled remotely-- you have to connect to the lock itself, or a device physically linked to it.

Comment: This seems the intent of the forum suggestion based on the real-world definition of hardwiring.